# AngularJS Dropdown not showing in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9

Following code below I tried to make it work in Chrome and it works but when I try in IE9, I am not able to get the results in the dropdown.
Changed my AngularJS version to  AngularJS v1.2.16 and angular.min.js : AngularJS v1.2.16
Still could not see any results.

```
 <div id="ng-app" ng-app="displayProductList">

                          <br><br>
                              <div ng-controller="ProductsListController">
                              <br>
                              <br>
                                  <div ng-show="products.length">
                                      <div>
                                          <select ng-model="product" ng-options="prod.name for prod in products" />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding a [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) to your project.

Hope that helps.